# NLTK Cross Validation for HMM Tagging

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

NLTK does not seem to have a cross validation method.

I was trying to develop an Hidden Markov Model (HMM) based tagger in NLTK. 
I found a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379313/how-to-use-the-a-10-fold-cross-validation-with-naive-bayes-classifier-and-nltk/16379570) on related topic. Based on the answers here if I try to write it as,

```
cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(train_corp), n_folds=10,shuffle=False)
    for traincv, testcv in cv:
        hmm_tagger=nltk.HiddenMarkovModelTagger.train(train_corp[traincv[0]:traincv[len(traincv)-1]])
        evaluation=hmm_tagger.evaluate(train_corp[testcv[0]:testcv[len(testcv)-1]])
        print evaluation
```

am I going fine?

If any one may kindly suggest.

Comment: Using `graphlab`, take a look at code no. [5] on https://github.com/alvations/stasis/blob/master/notebooks/SHIELD.ipynb.

Comment: For `scikit-learn`, take a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html